# Google Chrome Developer Tools shows my files twice. One can be edited, the other can be debugged

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a single page website using Visual Studio. During development I am using Google Chrome Developer Tools to debug but I **was** also able to change the files in Chrome. Also my changes were directly reflected in my Visual Studio environment.

I don't know what I have changed but currently my Google Chrome Developer Tools shows me each file twice when I am using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> I see the following result:

[image: Chrome Open File]

It is exactly the same file. But chrome behaves differently based on the selected result:

- selecting **www/index/scipts/index.js**

  - can be used to change the code (Also reflected in Visual Studio)
  - debugging **not** possible
- selecting **localhost/www/index/scripts/index.js**

  - not able to change
  - debugging works

#### workspace settings

- **Folder**: C:\TFS\MyBranch\www
- **Mappings**:

  - **URL prefix**: `http://localhost/www/`
  - **Folder path**: /

#### local iis settings

- Default Website (port:80)

  - www (path: C:\TFS\MyBranch\www)

#### Visual studio project settings

The 'www' project has following Web settings:

- **Servers**:

  - **Type**: Local IIS
  - **Project Url**: `http://localhost/www/`
  - Virtual Directory is created
  - Able to browse to url

### Question

I have had it working that Chrome allowed me to edit and debug in the same opened file. How do I need to setup/change my environment to get this working again?

Comment: You need to add a mapping in the dev tools between files from your HTTP server and the filesystem.

Comment: @SLaks My Folder is `C:\TFS\MyBranch\www` and it maps to `http://localhost/www/` as mentioned in the `workspace settings` Are you referring to this mapping or do I miss another required mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click `index.js` in the Sources panel and in the context menu select `Map to File System Resource...` (or `Map to Network Resource...`, depends on whether you click the network or workspace resource,) then choose its counterpart to establish the actual workspace mapping.