# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at (index):1

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have been staring at this code for like 2 hours and I can not figure out where I am going wrong here. Chrome keeps telling me that I have unexpected identifier at (index):1. For reference, in my index.html at line 1, the code is simply `<!DOCTYPE html>`, so I do not see where I am going wrong. Although, I have noticed Chrome created two index.html files, so I am not sure if that is part of the problem. If so, I have no clue how to stop it from duplicating the file.

[image]

Also, I tried running this in Firefox and it gave me a similar error:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ] after element list127.0.0.1:5500:1:24note: [ opened at line 1, column 16"

Edit: Here is the head element which contains all of my sources.

````
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Righteous&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
</head>```
````

Comment: Is there a <script> tag anywhere in the body of the HTML?

Comment: @Neil No, I searched through all of my files and that is the only place where there are script tags.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you have a javascript script (probably inside a <script></script> tag that has an error in it. See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_bracket_after_list

Comment: I just edited my post and I added my script tags. I do not see an error with them.

Comment: I don't understand then. That error message is a Javascript error message. Have you tried feeding your HTML though the HTML validator at https://validator.w3.org/ ?

Comment: yes, I did. I gave me an unrelated error that I fixed. However, the same error is still displayed.

Comment: I don't know what else to suggest. However, if you would like to put your HTML somewhere I could access (like pastebin.com) I could see if I could try to sort it for you. I understand if you don't want to make the code available though.

Comment: The reason for the 2 (index) files can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120434/google-chrome-developer-tools-shows-my-files-twice-one-can-be-edited-the-other